# How to create "in" operator query for multiple fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-performance, mongodb-indexes

I have a collection

```
db.list.insert({ first: "apple", second: "banana" });
db.list.insert({ first: "apple", second: "tree" });
db.list.insert({ first: "orange", second: "tree" });
db.list.insert({ first: "medal", second: "sport" });
```

I want to query for documents based on these two fields and fetch documents only when both fields match.

I have tried the following query

```
db.list.find(
  $or: [
     { first: 'apple', second: { $in: ['tree', 'banana']}},
     { first: 'orange', second: { $in: ['tree']}}
  ],
).limit(5);
```

and added indexes for

```
{first: 1, second: 1}
```

In the query plan, it generates same number of plans as the number of predicates in the "or" query. There are about 2 millions of documents and if it does not get its 5 document in the first predicate then it fetches all the documents matching all the predicates and the query times out.
Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Comment: there are other ways too but filters would remains same. Can you tell number of entries in collection and number of predicates in your query results timed out ?

Comment: Number of entries are around 2 million and it times out for about 5 predicates in "or" query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$facet** using mongodb **aggregation pipeline**. This will make sure documents are getting fetched only once. Here is the sample query

```
    db.list.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "condition_1": [
                {
                    "$match": { first: 'apple', second: { $in: ['tree', 'banana']}}
                },
                {
                    "limit": 5
                }
            ],
            "condition_2": [
                {
                    "$match": { first: 'orange', second: { $in: ['tree']}}
                },
                {
                    "limit": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    }
], {allowDiskUse: true})
```